# Anyone know how to fix a selector error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, protocols

I try to run my project in XCode and I get this error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDataSource2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88497f0'

All of the views/controllers in storyboard are named correctly and they're all part of the target membership of the class. I also use protocols, but I'm almost positive those are fine too.
However, it should be noted that I copied the storyboard in from another project if that would make a difference. Any ideas on what kind of error this is? I don't know where to begin. Even a general description would help.

Comment: You are getting the exception in the beginning itself? If no, please post some piece of code.

Comment: Yes in the beginning.

Comment: Please share your code. Let me have a look on that.

Comment: Whoops. I fixed it. For some reason it was referencing another class of the same name on my computer. I changed the name of the class and cleaned the build and that seemed to do it. Thank you for your response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your any UI Component is linked from setDataSource2 method but you not implement this method so its give this error..see in your storyboard any UI Component attached   setDataSource2 method then break this  conection.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), `UIView` doesn't have a `setDataSource2:` method.  It doesn't even have a `setDataSource:` method.  If you didn't add such a method, you shouldn't be calling it on a `UIView` object.

Comment: It's funny, I don't see that method anywhere in my code, nor in the storyboard.